# Joining a query result to a distinct dynamic query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I've been trying all day long to merge a simple query result of a single row to another dynamic query with a single row. To briefly explain what I've got is as follows:

I have a query as a result of a complex SELECT that returns a single row of two columns:

```
HistoryDate |TotalMarketValue
2014-08-31   1195687865.20
```

Then I have another dynamic query which returns a single row with dynamic number of columns, where I do not know the name nor number of columns that would be returned, which I execute something like this:

```
exec sp_executesql @query
```

So basically what I need to do is something like:

```
SELECT HistoryDate, SUM(TotalMarketValue) FROM MyComplexTable, exec sp_executesql @query
```

Obviously the above syntax is wrong as the exec part will not allow me to do a CROSS JOIN. I've tried various other ways like attempting to populate the dynamic query results to a temporary table, but then again it doesn't allow me to create a table without specifying the number of columns. I'm just missing that point.

Can somebody let me know how I could get the dynamic query as part of the merged query?

Comment: Can you change `@query`so that you add the two extra columns into it, before you `sp_executesql` it?

Comment: Thank you very much @StuartLC, Just wondering why I couldn't figure out that angle for the whole day. Apparently the "TotalMarketValue" is enclosed with a SUM(function), and gave me some errors. Nevertheless your tip lead me towards the solution, by additionally adding the dynamic columns to the GROUP BY Clause.
Thank you very much again...! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a table variable and insert the results of the query into it. Then select the data from the table variable and your select statement with a union.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT HistoryDate, SUM(TotalMarketValue)'

DECLARE @Results TABLE(cola DATETIME, colb DECIMAL(18,2))

INSERT INTO @Results
exec sp_executesql @query

SELECT * FROM @Results
UNION 
SELECT HistoryDate, SUM(TotalMarketValue)
```